# Not found UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor 5.3.4f1

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

1. Open Download page click.
2. Not found.

need android build module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install the module from the unity installer. I have the same for iOS but that is because I decided do not install that module.
Note: you don't need to reinstall unity, just check the module you need in the dialog

Comment: I don`t understand at the begginning but it`s the installer that you downloaded from unity. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yahp. Thanks. Of course would be safe use the installer for the same version of unity that you have, not the latest installer  if you use a previous version.. But I'm just guessing. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

> Could not found UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor

**EDIT 1:**

---

**If Unity fails to install the Android package:**

---

Kindly do check, that the name for the folder in which <kbd>Unity3D</kbd> is installed is **"Unity"** and nothing else. Then try to install the Android package again, via installer.

[Unity Download Archive][1]

**If you still have problem after installation, you need to follow these steps:**

1. In the Application folder(For Mac) - Unity -> PlaybackEngines ->
   Copy AndroidPlayer folder.
2. After that Right click on Unity Package(Icon) -> Select "Show
   Package  Contents" -> Contents -> Select PlaybackEngines -> You Just
   Paste here(AndroidPlayer folder).
3. Restart Unity